# How do Shaivas and Shaktas interpret the Vishnu Gayatri mantra?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, shaivism, shaktism

How do Shaivas and Shaktas interpret the Vishnu Gayatri mantra, which is from the Narayana Suktam of the Yajur Veda:

> "Narayanaya vidmahe vasudevaya dhimahi | tanno Vishnuh prachodayat"

which identifies Narayana as Vishnu?

Comment: It would be worth to mention where in the scriptures that mantra is located.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Narayana Suktam from the Yajur Veda.

Comment: Yes, I knew that but some people who read questions here on Hi SE don't know that thing. For their sake you may want to mention that thing in your Q.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I added it now.

Comment: Why would Shaivas, Shaktas interpret this mantra? What is their problem if Vishnu is Narayana? @Ikshvaku